# Android access battery stats or monitoring battery level through manifest

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I want to detect battery change at every percentage. I tried to create a service with

```
context.registerReceiver(this.myBatteryReceiver,new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
```

but when the application is closed the service is killed.

I tried to register my broadcast receiver in the manifest with `<action android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED" />` but the documentation says:

> You can not receive this through components declared in manifests, only by explicitly registering for it with Context.registerReceiver().

What can I do to monitor the battery level even if the app is closed?

I have seen the permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BATTERY_STATS" />`. Can I use it? And if yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What can I do to monitor the battery level even if the app is closed ?

Use `AlarmManager` to check for the battery level periodically. You can call `registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));` to retrieve the last-broadcast `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` `Intent`. Allow the user to control the polling period (e.g., every minute, every 5 minutes), and probably do not use a `_WAKEUP` alarm, so you will only check the battery level when the device is otherwise in use.

Comment: yes, but the app needs to be started if I register an AlarmManager right ? According to me this code will probably not work if the app is closed : `AlarmManager alarm_manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarm_manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, date.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY , pending_intent);`

Comment: @user2683000: "but the app needs to be started if I register an AlarmManager right" -- you need to get control once to set up your alarms, such as on the first run of your app. You need to get control again on a reboot, as a reboot wipes out all scheduled alarms. Otherwise, `AlarmManager` is *specifically designed* to trigger your code *without* you having a currently-running process at the time.

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer, I understand now. AlarmManager works well !